# listing folders and naming in batch

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, dos

Im now trying to improve my old script with your knowledge

here is my actual script

```
@echo off
SET DSESS=%CD:~22,6%
SET SSESS=P_S013
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d %DSESS%_*.png') do (
convert %%i -resize 1500x1500 %%~ni.jpg
)

mkdir \\Nascfmj1\DOCNUM\partition\entier\%SSESS%\%DSESS%
move *.jpg \\Nascfmj1\DOCNUM\partition\entier\%SSESS%\%DSESS%

mkdir \\Nascfmj1\DOCNUM\partition\conservation\%SSESS%\%DSESS%
copy *.png \\Nascfmj1\DOCNUM\partition\conservation\%SSESS%\%DSESS%

copy *.pdf \\Nascfmj1\DOCNUM\partition\entier\%SSESS%

convert *0001.png -resize 1500x1500 %DSESS%_COUV.jpg
copy *_COUV.jpg \\Nascfmj1\DOCNUM\partition\pochette\%SSESS%
```

---

As you see nothing extravagant

I run the script from `I:\2013CAPTURE\b-p_98\P_1345`
In the actual situation, if i change the ciontaining folder naming the script wont recognise the right path (`%CD:~22,6%`)

in `I:\2013CAPTURE\b-p_98\` there is a list of folders starting from `P_1000` to actual `P_1345`
could i run the script from `I:\2013CAPTURE\b-p_98\` and tell batch to get into each folder, proceed to script by nanming DSESS with the name of the folder? Notice also that inside the folder all the files are named with this typoology (`P_1000_0001.png`)

Thank you for your precious help

Dan

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
::
:: These are YOUR relative-root (base of scanning tree)
:: and destination
:: No idea where SSESS appears from... :(
::
SET SSESS=P_5013

SET relroot=I:\2013CAPTURE\b-p_98
SET dest=\\Nascfmj1\DOCNUM\partition

::
:: These are MY directories used for testing
::
SET dest=C:\destdir\%ssess%
SET relroot=u:\b-p_98

SET entier=%dest%\entier\%SSESS%
SET conservation=%dest%\conservation\%SSESS%
SET pochette=%dest%\pochette\%SSESS%

::
:: This is for a test - creating dummy files
:: 3 directories, 3 ".png" files in each, 
::
FOR /L %%i IN (1000,1,1002) DO (
 MD %relroot%\p_%%i
 FOR /L %%f IN (2000,1,2002) DO (
   dir>%relroot%\p_%%i\p_%%i_%%f.png
 )
)


::
:: Routine proper - create pochette
::
MD %pochette%
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir /ad/b "%relroot%\P_????" ' ) DO (
 PUSHD "%relroot%\%%a"
 FOR /f %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d P_*.png ') DO (
  CALL :CONVERT %%i -resize 1500x1500 %%~ni.jpg
 )

 MD %entier%\%%a
 move *.jpg %entier%\%%a

 mkdir %conservation%\%%a
 copy *.png %conservation%\%%a

 copy *.pdf %entier%

 CALL :convert *0001.png -resize 1500x1500 %%a_COUV.jpg
 copy *_COUV.jpg %pochette%

 POPD

)

GOTO :eof

::
:: I don't have CONVERT.EXE...
::
:CONVERT
ECHO execute command: CONVERT %*
::
:: Two different situations:
:: either create DUMMY .PDF and .JPG
:: OR DUMMY _COUV
ECHO %*|FINDSTR /i "couv" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
DIR >%4
DIR >%~n4.PDF
) ELSE (
DIR >%4
)
GOTO :eof
```

This should do the task - well, I'd hardly be posting it if it didn't, would I?

I've no idea where SSESS comes from, so I've just `SET` it at the start of the file.

`relroot` is set to where the scan should start, `dest` to where the files will be moved or copied. I immediately reset them to MY test directories - I'd suggest for testing you set up a similar tree of realistic data.

Then the `entier`, `conservation` and `pochette` directories are calculated.

I've then created some dummy ".png" files and diretories in my testing area.

I noticed that you're not making `pochette` in your routine, so I made one.

Then the main routine - 
Each directoryname matching P_???? in the directory `%relroot%` is assigned in turn to `%%a`, so `%%a` replaces `%DSESS%`

The PUSHD changes to the selected directoryname, and you should be familiar with the `CONVERT` command. I called a subroutine to simulate the creation of a `.jpg` and made a `.pdf` at the same time.

When the `.png`s have been processed, the subdirectory of `entier` is made and the appropriate `.jpg`s moved to it. Same story with `conservation` and the `.pdf`s are copied to the `entier` directory.

Finally, the `convert` routine is called again to complete the `*_couv.jpg` file which can then be moved to `pochette`

The POPD restores the original directory and we continue until all of the directories are done.

So this routine could be run from ANYWHERE - it doesn't matter what the current directory is.

Good testing!

HTH